# How to trigger standard HTML5 form validation without submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have this form in my app and I will submit it via AJAX, but I want to use HTML5 for client-side validation. So I want to be able to force the form validation, via normal HTML field.

I want to trigger the validation without submitting the form. Is it possible?

HTML Code Example

```
<form id="frm" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="6" data-validate-words="2" name="name" placeholder="both name(s) e.g Jon Doe" required="required" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <button id="send" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="saveForm()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<hr />
<button id="checkValidity">Check Validity</button>
```

Comment: Just a side note, client side validation is used for convenience for the client, but you also need server side validation because that is used for security. The client can change anything you have for validation with HTML5 and send you invalid  information. You want to make sure you catch this too. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using HTML5 validation, it won't *let* you submit the form if you give your button a `submit` type if there's some invalid data.

Also, it doesn't look like you don't need to use another method to submit the form. Your button:

```
<button id="send" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="saveForm()">Submit</button>
```

calls a function `saveForm()`, so in that function, before you send your AJAX request, do any extra JS validation you want and then `return` early if you see it's invalid

Answer (score 1):

You can manually check form validity using the `checkValidity()` method that is also raising the `invalid` event for each of the invalid elements in your form:

```
$('#checkValidity').click(function() {

    // register named event handler for further removal
    $('input:invalid').on('invalid.temp', function(e) {
        // input is invalid
    });

    // trigger validation
    frm.checkValidity();

    // remove event handlers
    $('input:invalid').off('invalid.temp');

});
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6e8a3a5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but why do you want to do it? If you want to change style or display an error message you can do so with CSS.

On MDN there is an [interesting article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) on form validation.

If it's about styling you can use the [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) pseudo class for example.

It would be helpful to know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. Once you have [enough rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) you'll be able to add comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't validate all the fields without submitting, only thing you can do is to trigger validation on Onblur of each of the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

No if you want to use, the `required` attribute for form validations then you need to submit the form. The other thing you can do which is very lengthy is have onblur and onfocus listeners on all input elements and validate the form with javascript. This is lengthy but gives a better user experience, as validation occurs on the fly and not at the end while submitting.